# Call google sheets API from VB .net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I made an ASP .Net web application with visual basic.
I need to get data from a google sheet document. But I have no clue where to start.
So far I've googled and only got my data to show in a c# console application, but that's not what I need.

Any idea on how to call this google sheets API from my web application in visual basic? 
Or would you recommend switching over to C# from vb?

Comment: Why can't you use same logic as in C# code?

Comment: it's a console application and everything there is in the same program.cs class. I wouldn't know where to start in vb where I would pass on my credentials and eventually get the data to show in my index

Comment: So? You could make your google sheets data fetcher class and use similar calls as in console application. Or do you want to use google sheets as some kind of data provider, link your grids-controls directly to it etc? Then sorry, I have no clue :(

Comment: Most of the differences between C# and VB are just spelling differences for the same underlying capabilities and features.  What don't you know how to translate from C# to VB?

Comment: use converted to convert c# code to vb.net